# How to compare two columns and input the smaller one in a new column in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am working on a DataFrame that looks like this. I'd like to choose the faster date of the two and put it into another column.

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-03 | 2015-01-04 |  |
| 2022-02-22 | 2017-01-02 |  |

and my desired out put is

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-03 | 2015-01-04 | 2015-01-03 |
| 2022-02-22 | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |

So far I've tried

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, "col1"] < df.loc[i, "col2"]:
        df.loc[i, "col3"] = df.loc[i, "col1"]
    else:
        df.loc[i, "col3"] = df.loc[i, "col2"]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your question. Can you please share what you have tried so far in order for us to help you along with your own code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `min` on axis:

```
df['col3'] = df[['col1','col2']].min(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
         col1        col2        col3
0  2015-01-03  2015-01-04  2015-01-03
1  2022-02-22  2017-01-02  2017-01-02
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` functions giving `axis` attribute as `1` in order to run the function through the rows:

```py
df["col1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col1"])
df["col2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col2"])

df["col3"] = df.apply(min, axis=1)
df
```

Note that, the first two lines are to make sure that the values are datetime objects.

##### Output

```
    col1        col2        col3
0   2015-01-03  2015-01-04  2015-01-03
1   2022-02-22  2017-01-02  2017-01-02
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert your columns to datetime format and then use the where method:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame.from_records([["2015-01-03",  "2015-01-04"], 
                                  ["2022-02-22",  "2017-01-02"]], 
                                 columns=["col1", "col2"])
for col in data:
    data[col] = pd.to_datetime(data[col])
data['col3'] = data['col1'].where(data['col1']<data['col2'], data['col2'])
```

Result looks like:

```
        col1       col2       col3
0 2015-01-03 2015-01-04 2015-01-03
1 2022-02-22 2017-01-02 2017-01-02
```